# Getting data from datagrid returns empty strings

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

In a project, I am trying to get the data which has been inserted into the `datagrid` from the `datagrid` but the data I am getting null strings for all the fields.

The xaml declaration of the datagrid is:

```
<DataGrid  RowEditEnding="linesGrid_RowEditEnding" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="linesGrid" />
```

And the event I am using for getting the data is RowEditEnding, but I am not getting the data of the new row, the implementation of the event handler is:

```
String LineID;
        String Connection_Type;

        //MessageBox.Show(linesGrid.Items.Count.ToString());


        for (int i = 0; i < linesGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            System.Data.DataRowView item = (System.Data.DataRowView)linesGrid.Items[3];

            //fetch columns
            LineID = item.Row[0].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(LineID);
            Connection_Type = item.Row[1].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(Connection_Type);

        }
```

What is the thing that I am doing wrong because the message box is getting strings which are empty.

Comment: have you placed a break point and stepped through your code to see if there is a message thats being lost or if its reading the wrong cell or if its just not doing anything?

EDIT: remember its a 0 based index, so that 3 is actually line 4

Comment: Message is lost because I have tried printing the values of all columns

Comment: Can you see the data when you run the program?

Comment: yes. I already have 3 rows that are being displayed. but when I enter new one I get null values for that row.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you looping and not using the i from the loop?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < linesGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView item = (System.Data.DataRowView)linesGrid.Items[3];

        //fetch columns
        LineID = item.Row[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(LineID);
        Connection_Type = item.Row[1].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Connection_Type);

    }
```

Do you mean?

```
    System.Data.DataRowView item = (System.Data.DataRowView)linesGrid.Items[i];
```

Comment: Actually yes it's i. *Typo* here

Comment: So you are seeing the values in grid itself?

Comment: yes. I already have 3 rows that are being displayed. but when I enter new one I get null values for that row.

Comment: Check (debug) the set on the classes and be sure the new data is getting in the object.